# Find the next key id in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stored an object in one variable (Consider as datatable).

```
var data=[{"controlID":"A","currentValue":"10","onChange":"","onClick":""},
        {"controlID":"B","currentValue":"5","onChange":"Testing(A,B)","onClick":""},
        {"controlID":"C","currentValue":"-5","onChange":"Testing1(A,B)","onClick":""},
        {"controlID":"D","currentValue":"","onChange":"Testing2(B,C)","onClick":""},{"controlID":"E","currentValue":"","onChange":"Testing3(C,D)","onClick":""},{"controlID":"F","currentValue":"","onChange":"","onClick":""}];
```

Now I know the second row key value as B. How to I Get the Third row (i.e., "C" row values)

Am new of this field. Please help us to helpful.

Comment: what you have tried ?? add code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects   u need this. probably duplicate.

Comment: How to I get the index of 'B'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This function will return your index:**

```
var FindIndexOfControlID = function(id, data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
        if( data[i]['controlID'] == id ){
            return i;
        }
    }
};
```

**Usage:**

```
var index = FindIndexOfControlID('C', data);
```

**Live Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/medhgm7b/

---

**NOTE**

> Alternatively you may also want to implement function that returns `index` of any specified `property` and `value`:

```
var FindIndexOfProperty = function(value, property, data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
        if( data[i][property] == value ){
            return i;
        }
    }
};
```

> Usage

```
FindIndexOfProperty('-5', 'currentValue',data); // returns 2
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know 'B' th position. Then how to I give the data[2]. Or how to find the B'th row index.

Comment: Hi I need one more. i.e., var temp=Testing(A,B,C,D). I need A,B,C,D in different variable or in array list. Any predefined class or example is there.....

Comment: create new question I might answer it :)

Comment: please see my question "Get the Variable name inside the function in javascript"

Answer (score 0):

You can return the third row in javascript by simply executing `var thirdRow = data[2]`. The row will be returned as an object.